# Same data from checkbox value

Tags: javascript

```
<li><a href="#">WSN</a>
      <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/qabala.php" onchange="getline();" onclick="boxclick(this,'qabala')" /> Qabala</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/ismailli.php"  onchange="getline();" onclick="boxclick(this,'ismailli')" /> Ismayilli</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value"  value="wsn/agshu.php"  onchange="getline();" onclick="boxclick(this,'aghsu')" /> Aghsu</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/shamakhi.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'shamakhi')" /> Shamakhi</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/shabran.php"  onchange="getline();" onclick="boxclick(this,'shabran')" /> Shabran</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/siyazan.php"  onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'siyazan')" /> Siyazan</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/jalilabad.php"   onchange="getline();" onclick="boxclick(this,'jalilabad')" /> Jalilabad</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value"  value="wsn/masalli.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'masalli')" /> Masalli</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/lerik.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'lerik')" /> Lerik</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="value" value="wsn/yardimli.php" onchange="getline();"  onclick="boxclick(this,'yardimli')" /> Yardimli</li>

      </ul>
```

I have changed it. It works but I get only first data. Why is this? **[only wsn/qabala.php]**

Comment: Clarify what you trying to say

Comment: how you call it in javascript

Comment: how many events for this..!onchange..onclick..?what else is remaining

Comment: I guess, you're trying to call it via `id`... All your `id`s are "value"

Comment: id should always be unique

Comment: Your code is incorrect. ID must be unique for each element. The only exception to this rule is radio buttons.

Comment: @ChrisBain I think that's an answer!

Comment: sorry.. for late answer:  i get data:  var getd = document.getElementById('value').value;

Comment: @brio follow the ChrisBain that i must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id must be unique if you are calling with id

script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function boxclick(checkvalue,str,chk)
    {
        var lfckv = document.getElementById(chk).checked
        alert(lfckv)
        alert(checkvalue);
        alert(str);
        if(lfckv)
        {
            //code on checked
        }
        else
        {
            //code on unchecked
        }

    }
</script>
```

html

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value1" value="wsn/qabala.php" onclick="boxclick(this.value,'qabala','value1')" /> Qabala</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value2" value="wsn/ismailli.php"  onclick="boxclick(this.value,'ismailli','value2')" /> Ismayilli</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value3"  value="wsn/agshu.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'value3')" /> Aghsu</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value4" value="wsn/shamakhi.php"  onclick="boxclick(this.value,'shamakhi','value4')" /> Shamakhi</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value5" value="wsn/shabran.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'shabran','value5')" /> Shabran</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value6" value="wsn/siyazan.php"    onclick="boxclick(this.value,'siyazan','value6')" /> Siyazan</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value7" value="wsn/jalilabad.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'jalilabad','value7')" /> Jalilabad</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value8"  value="wsn/masalli.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'masalli','value8')" /> Masalli</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value9" value="wsn/lerik.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'lerik','value9')" /> Lerik</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value10" value="wsn/yardimli.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'yardimli','value10')" /> Yardimli</li>

  </ul>
```

you can call it with function as you are mentioned

`boxclick(this.value)`

Comment: thanks for answer.. but how can i get this data ?> 
 i get it liek that: var getd = document.getElementById('value').value;

Comment: as you are calling function `boxclick(this.value)`

Comment: as soon as i reach to office i will do it for you ok

Answer (score 1):

id must be unique for you to reference the control.

because all of your IDs are 'value' it is just returning the first one.